# Can't get rid of Split package, multiple jars provide the same package

Tags: java, maven, osgi, apache-felix, maven-bundle-plugin

I have main project (projectA), which has a library depencency (projectB), both has `package.subpackage` in them. I would like to inline the library in the main project. Main project configuration is quite simple (in addition the the depencency listed with 'compile' scope:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.0</version>
    <extensions>true</extensions>
    <configuration>
        <instructions combine.inherited="append">
            ...
            <Export-Package>package.*;version=${packet.version};-split-package:=merge-first</Export-Package>
            <Bundle-SymbolicName>${project.artifactId};singleton=true</Bundle-SymbolicName>
        </instructions>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Yet it yields following warning

```
--- maven-bundle-plugin:2.4.0:bundle (default-bundle) @ projectA ---
Bundle project:projectA:bundle:version : Split package, multiple jars provide the same package:project/subproject
Use Import/Export Package directive -split-package:=(merge-first|merge-last|error|first) to get rid of this warning
Package found in   [Jar:., Jar:subproject]
Class path         [Jar:., Jar:subproject]
```

I have split-package directive yet the warning persists.

What I would love it a way to simply inline everything from the explicitly listed artifact and nothing more (even if there are more dependencies stated), without any transitive dependencies. Preferably without any warnings about split package.

Answer (score -1):

I think that you need the [maven shade plug-in](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/)

Comment: Why would adding in another plugin help?

Comment: Because it is designed specifically to solve this problem, and generally plugins are using in maven build systems to handle dependencies and configuration.

Comment: If the packages are in two separate third party JARs, it won't solve this. The compile will fail-fast before the shader is run.